# How can I use tensorflow pretrained model (i.e inception v3) in batch mode by using GPU?

Tags: gpu, tensorflow

I wanna use the inception v3 model in tensor flow for feature extraction. But the number of the images I am using is a lot, so it takes long time to run. So, I am going to use GPU. I have installed Cuda 7.5 and cuDnn correctly. 
I am using following code in the CPU mode for one image:

```
with tf.Session as sess:
    softmax_tensor =sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('pool_3:0')
    feat_vect = numpy.squeeze(sess.run(softmax_tensor,{'DecodeJpeg:0':       in_image}))
```

So, my question is that how should I change my code so I can use it for many batches by GPU?

Comment: It's a bit hard to say without more details of your code. But I would suggest you take a look at the Inception code in the Tensorflow models repository: it supports evaluation over batches. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_eval.py

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

Comment: Thanks for your response, In my program I just load the inception v3 graph and then I use above code to extract the feature from pool_3 layer for image in_image. I looked at code of Tensorflow models repository but it is still a little confusing for me.